# Norm of quotients

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

$\newcommand{\Ker}{\operatorname{Ker}}$

Let $X$ be Hilbert space and let $T:X\to X$ be a bounded operator. Define the operator
 $S: X/\Ker T \to X/\Ker T$ via $S(x+\Ker T)=Sx+\Ker T$. I can show that $||S||\leq ||T||$, and I am wondering whether the norms are actually equal. Is this true or false in general?

Edit: Considering the answer below, I am adding the conditions that $\Ker(T)$ is finite dimensional and $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ is not (say $T$ is surjective). Could you please show a counterxample in this situation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $T^2 = 0$. Then $\text{im}(T) \subseteq \text{ker}(T)$, so...

**Edit:** The extra conditions do not really change anything. Here is an example where $T$ is surjective and $\text{ker}(T)$ is one-dimensional. Let $T$ act on a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2, ...$ by
$$T e_1 = 0$$
$$T e_2 = 2 e_1$$
$$T e_n = \frac{1}{2} e_{n-1}, n \ge 3.$$

The point here is that $\text{ker}(T)$ may still contain the part of the image of $T$ which determines its norm.

Comment: Just to add to Qiaochu's answer, if $ker(T)$ and $im(T)$ are orthogonal then the norms are equal. Otherwise, even if $ker(T)$ and $im(T)$ don't intersect, the norms could be different.

Comment: @Theo: right. In particular this is the case if $T$ is self-adjoint.